# Java Spring Boot Override Annotation Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I'm writing a Java Spring Boot Web App, and the issue I'm experiencing for the following class is only occurring in one place:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import bcoreHW.model.SiteUser;
import bcoreHW.model.UserRepo;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    // likely unnecessary
    public void register(SiteUser user) {
        userRepo.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        SiteUser user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");

        String password = user.getPassword();

        return new User(username, password, auth);
    }

}
```

On the loadUserByUsername() method, there is the following error: "The method loadUserByUsername(String) of type UserService must override a superclass method", and it says that I can remove this error by removing the @Override annotation, which I don't want to do. This is the only place this is occurring in the entire project with other @Override annotations as well, and I also have the latest JRE. So I'm not sure what the issue could be. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Where you the error? In IDE (what IDE), in some build tool (Maven, Gradle)? 2) How did you check what Java version you are using?

Comment: Using Eclipse with Maven and I went to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Comment: What Java version you have in POM?

Comment: Look for `maven-compiler-plugin` in POM. There should be a version specified. Tell me this version.

Comment: I don't have  maven-compiler-plugin, but I have spring-boot-maven-plugin, but there is no version with this. In <properties> I have java.version 1.8, though.

Comment: It's fine. Can you build it not in the IDE, but in the console? 1) In the console run `java -version` and tell what version you see. 2) Compile your code with maven,  for instance, `mvn clean package` (or `mvnw ...` if you used initializr). Do you see any errors?